# Differentiabilty of certain convolution

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, integral-equations

Let $\Gamma$ be a smooth closed curve. Suppose $f\in L^2(\Gamma,ds)$ and $g$ is defined everywhere on $\mathbb{C}$ with compact support. Moreover $\frac{dg}{dz}$ exists everywhere but point $z=0$. Then can we conclude $f{*}g=\int_\Gamma f(w)g(w-z)ds(w)$ is differentiable?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I hope that convolution is differentiable everywhere on $\Gamma$

Comment: Forgive me if I mis-remember, but doesn't analyticity of $g$ on $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$ along with $g$ being defined on *all* of $\mathbb{C}$ imply that $g$ has analytic continuation to all of $\mathbb{C}$? Then the rule for the derivative under the integral sign should give you the result you need, right?

Comment: $g$ is not analytic a priori. we just know that $\frac{dg}{dz}$exists.

Comment: I'm now consulting my old course notes. If $g$ is differentiable in a region, then it is by definition holomorphic in this region. Now $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$ is a region (connected open set). Since $g$ is defined everywhere on $\mathbb{C}$, and is holomorphic away from 0, its derivative has a removable singularity at 0, and indeed we can find entire $\tilde{g}$ which agrees with $g$ except at 0. Now, we assume d$s$ is a measure on $\Gamma$. Since $f*g$ involves an integral of $g$ (weighted by $f$, roughly) along $\Gamma$, the crux is whether or not $\Gamma$ intersects 0, and if so...

Comment: ...whether or not d$s$ assigns a Dirac mass at 0. Can you offer more information regarding this? Otherwise you can only hope for a case-wise answer.

Comment: I apologise, I notice now that $g$ could have a pole at $0$, and simply be defined to take some non-zero value at $0$. I suspect that the answer you desire hinges very much on the specifics of the situation: how $g$ behaves near $0$, whether $\Gamma$ intersects $0$, and whether d$s$ assigns a point mass to $0$.

Comment: $ds$ is arc length measure.say $g(x)=\ln|x|$